# Apacite - changing "ed." / "edition" brackets in generated bibliography entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, apa-style

I need explicit entrys in my (german) normed bibliography. After a lot of work i have settled with apacite, because it sounded like it could do the stuff i need. So far i am able to change: Title, Year, Publisher, Adress by `\renewcommand`'ing commands out of the `apacite.sty`. 


Author is missing and i have not found any relation to the edition in the file. I tried to change practically everything that had anything to do with ed. or edition.

Can someone tell me which functions change the author and edition brackets? 

It would also be nice if someone knows how to change the order of the outcome in the bibliography. I haven't gotten into it yet.


Here 2 examples of what is happening. First is the one I get, the second is the one i need.

> Bocuse, P. 1977. Die neue Küche (1. translated ed.). Düsseldorf: Econ.

> Bocuse 1977 
>  Bocuse, Paul: Die Neue Küche.
>   1. translated edition. Düsseldorf: Econ, 1977.

Edit:
I hoped code wouldn't be necessary since nothing actually has to do with the implementation, that's as far as i know. I included all my usepackages, maybe they are needed too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% Norm von A4 Buchform
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\geometry{top=25mm,bottom=25mm,footskip=20mm,headsep=15mm}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage [utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage [pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{units}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[pdftex]{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{longtable}

%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% Citing and Bibliography
%~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\usepackage{apacite}

% Testing area
% This actually changes "something" with the author(s), 
% it makes the title go into a new line

\renewenvironment{APACrefauthors}{%
  \begingroup \APACrefauthstyle
}{\endgroup }


% Title
\renewcommand{\APACrefbtitle}[2]{\Bem{#2}}

% Year
\renewcommand{\APACrefYear}[1]{%
  {#1}%
}

% Adress and Publisher
\renewcommand{\APACaddressPublisher}[2]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      {#2}%                 publisher
    \fi
  \else
    {#1}%                   address
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      \unskip: {#2}%        publisher
    \fi
  \fi
}


% Doesn't do anything with my citing
\renewcommand{\BVOL}{Vol.\hbox{}}       % volume (of a multi-volume book)
\renewcommand{\BVOLS}{Vols.\hbox{}}     % volumes
\renewcommand{\BEd}{ed.\hbox{}}         % edition
\renewcommand{\APACrefatitle}[2]{#2}
\renewcommand{\APACrefaetitle}[2]{[#2]}
\renewcommand{\APACrefbetitle}[2]{[#2]}
\renewcommand{\BVOLS}{Vols.\hbox{}}     % volumes
\renewcommand{\APACjournalVolNumPages}[4]{%
  \Bem{#1}%             journal
  \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, \Bem{#2}%  volume
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#3\@empty
  \else
    \unskip({#3})%      issue number
  \fi
  \ifx\@empty#4\@empty
  \else
    \unskip, {#4}%      pages
  \fi
}
\renewcommand{\APACaddressPublisher}[2]{%
  \ifx\@empty#1\@empty
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      {#2}%                 publisher
    \fi
  \else
    {#1}%                   address
    \ifx\@empty#2\@empty
    \else
      \unskip: {#2}%        publisher
    \fi
  \fi
}



\begin{document}

\citeauthor{bocuse} \citeyear{bocuse}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}


\listoffigures
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Literaturverzeichnis.bib contains:

```
@book{bocuse, 
    address ={Düsseldorf},  
    author   ={Bocuse, Paul},  
    edition ={1. übersetzte},  
    title    ={Die Neue Küche},  
    publisher={Econ,},  
    year     ={1977}   
}
```

I think thats it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after I was not able to solve it with apacite, I decided to start from scratch and solved it with Biblatex. I will describe now what I did.

First thing I needed to do was update everything I had in Miktex.
After that, I started to create my own .bbx and .cbx files. I named them **techdoku**. So I had techdoku.bbx and techdoku.cbx; cbx for cite and bbx for bibliography.

Location:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\bbx
>   C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\biblatex\cbx

That's where they needed to be placed and where I got my original style from.
My bbx file contained the style from **authortitle.bbx** and **standard.bbx**, my cbx the style of **authoryear.cbx**.

First thing I did after inserting my techdoku style (bbx and cbx into the folders) was setting up my `\usepackage` in my tex file.

```
\usepackage[
   style=techdoku, 
   backend=bibtex
   ]{biblatex}  

\setlength{\bibitemsep}{10pt} 
\setlength{\bibhang}{0pt} 


\bibliography{Literaturverzeichnis}
```

Afterwards the bbx entry had to be modified with the following (at kind of the top of the page, don't know if it's important):

```
\newbibmacro*{begentry}{
\usebibmacro{cite}}

\newbibmacro*{finentry}{\finentry}

% Doppelpunkt nach dem Autor
\renewcommand *{\labelnamepunct }{\addcolon \space }

\newcommand*{\bibmultinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
\newcommand*{\bibfinalnamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}% 
\AtBeginBibliography{% 
  \let\multinamedelim\bibmultinamedelim 
  \let\finalnamedelim\bibfinalnamedelim 
} 

\renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\space} 

\DeclareNameFormat{last-first}{% 
\iffirstinits 
  {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}} 
  {\usebibmacro{name:last-first}{#1}{#4}{#5}{#7}}% 
\usebibmacro{name:andothers}} 

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}%
```

My new entry for category Book:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \usebibmacro{bibindex}%
  \usebibmacro{begentry}%
  \usebibmacro{authortechdoku}% Autor ohne Jahreszahl
  \setunit{\labelnamepunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{maintitle+title}%
  \newunit
  \printlist{language}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byauthor}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{edition}%
  \newunit
  \iffieldundef{maintitle}
{\printfield{volume}%
 \printfield{part}}
{}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{volumes}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{series+number}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \printfield{note}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{location+publisher+year}%
  %\newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{chapter+pages}%
  \newunit
  \printfield{pagetotal}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:isbn}
{\printfield{isbn}}
{}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{doi+eprint+url}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{addendum+pubstate}%
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{related}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

A new Macro for my Year, Address and Publisher:

```
\newbibmacro*{location+publisher+year}{%
  \printlist{location}%
  \iflistundef{publisher}
    {\setunit*{\addcomma\space}}
    {\setunit*{\addcolon\space}}%
  \printlist{publisher}%
  \setunit*{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{yeartechdoku}%
}
```

A new definition of year without brackets

```
% Jahr ohne Klammern
\newbibmacro*{yeartechdoku}{% 
  \iffieldundef{year} 
{} 
{ 
   \printfield{year}% 
}}
```

And a changed author:

```
\renewbibmacro*{authortechdoku}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{bbx:dashcheck}
       {\bibnamedash}
       {\usebibmacro{bbx:savehash}%
        \printnames{author}%
    \iffieldundef{authortype}
      {\setunit{\addspace}}
      {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}}%
     \iffieldundef{authortype}
       {}
       {\usebibmacro{authorstrg}%
    \setunit{\addspace}}}%
    {\global\undef\bbx@lasthash
     \usebibmacro{labeltitle}%
     \setunit*{\addspace}}%
}
```

Afaik that's all for the bbx file.
cbx:

```
% Ändern des "and/und" in der Auflistung der Autoren
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{3}{\finalandcomma}{}%
   \addspace\addcomma\space}
```

I think that's it, this changes the "and" in the cite command to a comma.
The bibliography can be taken from the question, I tested this with an MWE following now.

```
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\begin{document}

\cite{bocuse}


\nocite{*}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

and I finally got:
cite:

> Bocuse 1977

Bibliography

> Bocuse 1977
>   Bocuse, Paul: Die neue Küche.
>   1. translated Edition. Düsseldorf: Econ, 1977.

Edit: Something I forgot: Unfortunately I wasn't able to get a "new line command" at some points, so I had to improvise in the bib file. Would like to know what I can do to do it better in the comments because this isn't optimal.

> @book{bocuse,
>     address ={Düsseldorf},
>         author   ={\Bocuse, Paul},
>     edition ={\1. übersetzte Auflage},
>         title    ={Die Neue Küche},
>     publisher={Econ,},
>         year     ={1977}
>   }